# Android Studio 2.0 preview 4 won't run if we delete or move the last opened project manually

Tags: android

Steps to Reproduce: Open one project in Android Studio and then close AS. Delete that project manually from computer and then run again AS. It will not start.

Any help ?

Comment: It's still in development mode so it may be a bug in android studio

Comment: I know its a bug but can u tell me if Any how i can clear android studio cache and files of last opened project ?

Comment: Did Studio doesn't start at all or it exits after few screens

Comment: It will just initialize and stuck with its progress reached at 100%

Answer (score 0):

In Windows there are two folders at location

C:Users/user_name : .android and .androidStudioPreview2.0

Just delete both of them and Android Studio will start setup like first time you have install it.